# Different between svelte global store and mobx store

Tags: state, svelte, mobx

```
import {writable, derived} from 'svelte/store'
```

What is exact different between [svelte store](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/writable-stores) and [mobx](https://mobx.js.org/) state management library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are *many* differences between the two libraries, but `mobx` is definitely a lot more sophisticated (and complicated!). This doesn't mean that mobx should be used as a replacement for `svelte/store` as svelte's store library is tightly integrated with svelte, for example:

```js
import { someStore } from "$lib/file"; 

// you can get the value of stores reactively in .svelte files with $
$: number = $someStore * 5
```

Conceptually, however, there are many similarities:

- "Computed" values in mobx are similar to svelte `derived`
- Svelte's "writable" is comparable to mobx's classes fields
- (As far as I know) there is no `readable` in `mobx` and it's [recommended to use external side effects](https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html)